# Swift - addGlobalMonitorForEvent not capturing Mouse Event

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying Swift to create a small prototype, that works well otherwise in .Net 6 for me. I am beginner in Swift.
I want to read Mouse Down event on other Application. What I have tried out so far that doesn't capture the Mouse Down event -

```
 public class EventMonitor {

  private var monitor: Any?
  private let mask: NSEvent.EventTypeMask = [NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseDown]
  private let handler: (NSEvent?) -> ()
  private let inactivityEvents: NSEvent.EventTypeMask = [NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseDown]
  public init(handler: @escaping (NSEvent?) -> ()) {
    self.handler = handler
    self.monitor = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: self.mask, handler: self.handler)
  }
  deinit {
    stop()
  }
  public func stop() {
    if self.monitor != nil {
      NSEvent.removeMonitor(self.monitor!)
      self.monitor = nil
    }
  }
} 


import SwiftUI
@main
struct test_accessibilityApp: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
      let noView: EmptyView = {
        test()
        return EmptyView()
      }()
      noView
    }
  }
  func test() {
    let em = EventMonitor(handler: event)
  }
  func event(e: NSEvent?) {
    print(e)
  }
}
```

I expected debugger to hit print(e) statement, which it doesn't. I have tried to see if Enabling Accessibility could be an option. Like I mentioned, I could get it working in .Net 6 without any issue. I will appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Is `em` deallocated at the end of `test()`?

Answer (score 0):

The `test_accessibilityApp` is struct, so does the `EmptyView` , so `test()` method only work once, when it's finished, your `em` object is released, try use state or StateObject